# NSTextField Key Interface Control (KIC) behaviour

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift, nstextfield

Background: I have a custom derivation of `NSTextField` that I am trying to use as a cell in a grid similar to a spreadsheet.

I have set the `nextKeyView` of my `NSTextField` and am confused between two states that the `NSTextField` can have *BOTH* of which involve it having the blue focus-ring drawn around it:

1. the cursor is blinking in it => in this case the TAB key behaves as expected and moves to the `nextKeyView` and it is in a "text accepting" mode
2. it has not quite "entered" the text field for the purposes of text editing => the TAB key does not respond with KIC behaviour and move to the `nextKeyView` and trying to enter any text just in fact results in the following:

> -[NSEvent key]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800012bf40

From background reading and a bit of debugging it appears that the first state corresponds to control/focus being handed off to the window's shared text editor and the custom `NSTextField` actually loses firstResponder status in this process.

What's interesting is how this differs from the behaviour of two standard `NSTextField` controls dragged onto an `NSView` in Interface Builder. Running such a simple app only the first state above is present at all as you tab from one `NSTextField` to the other! I am glad to have the intermediate second state in my app (because I need it) but I don't understand why it is happening...

**Summary: two related questions**

1. How do I programmatically control the `NSTextField` entering these two states of effectively accepting text and not while it has the focus [I do not know how to achieve this at all so this is my main problem...]
2. How can I get the KIC behaviour in the situation where the `NSTextField` has the focus but is not in "text editing" mode since this is the behaviour I am trying to get. [My current conclusion is that KIC does not work in this situation and that standard practise would be to resort to the regular overriding of `keyDown` for the set of keys that would normally be associated with KIC.]

Comment: Can you say a bit more about the gird? Does it subclass one of the grid-like Cocoa classes (e.g. ``NSTableView``), or is it entirely your own?

Comment: @PaulPatterson it is entirely custom spreadsheet-like grid.